# pdf not generating from dompdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I use dompdf for print invoices, but after upgrading php 7.2, it is stop working. When I print html then it is showing good but it is not render in pdf.

I use this code:

```
$invoice_template_dir = $smarty->template_dir 
.'/middle/expenses/';
html = $exp_obj->printPDFInvoice($invoice_template_dir);
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("dspl-invoice-" . $exp_obj->expense_id . ".pdf", 
array('Attachment' => 0));
    exit;
```

Comment: When I debug then it is showing like below:

body:
Id: 1
Class: Frame
Parent:html (0000000047d0b6950000000066a18416) 
Decorator: Block_Frame_Decorator
Position:
Array
(
    [x] => 0
    [y] => 0
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
)
Containing block:
Array
(
    [x] => 0
    [y] => 0
    [w] => 612
    [h] => 792
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 612
    [3] => 792
)

Comment: What errors is PHP throwing or logging when you attempt to render? Which version of Dompdf are you using? What version of PHP were you previously using?

Comment: Thanks @BrianS for the reply. I resolved the issue.